# How to get two forms (tables) to align beautifully and look pretty

Tags: html, css, forms, html-table

[Update]: A JSFiddle with the code (or what I was able to come up with as needed) - http://jsfiddle.net/CWwvC/1/

I am sorry for bothering you with something so lame, but I am stuck with a problem - you can see the issue here -

[image]

I've been searching in Google for the past 3 hours and I feel totally crushed now =[ There are solutions out there and I just feel like my mind has blocked and I can't think straight anymore =[
I will paste the whole Form HTML and the CSS part related to it.
Any help is deeply appreciated!
Thanks in advance!!!

HTML:

```
<form name='addUser' action="" method='post'>
    <table id="table" style="float: left;">
        <tr>
            <td><label for='professionOfChoice'>Desired Profession:</label></td>

            <td><select id='professionOfChoice' name='professionOfChoice' />

                <option value="1" <?php echo $professionOfChoice == '1' ?'selected="selected"' : '';?>>Journalist</option>
                <option value="2" <?php echo $professionOfChoice == '2' ?'selected="selected"' : '';?>>HR</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <br/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for='username'>Desired Username:</label></td>

            <td><input type='text' id='username' name='username' value="<?php echo $username;?>" />


                <?php echo empty($errors['username']) ? '' :
                    '<font color="red">'.$errors['username'].'</font>';?>
            </td>
            <td id="message"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <br />
            </td>
        </tr>              

        <tr>
            <td><label for='email'>Email:</label></td>

            <td><input type='text' id='email' name='email' value="<?php echo $email;?>" />
                <?php echo empty($errors['email']) ? '' : '<font color="red">'.$errors['email'].'</font>';?> </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>

                <br />
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>

            <td><label for='price'>Password:</label></td>

            <td><input type='password' id='password' name='password' />


                <?php echo empty($errors['password']) ? '' : 
                    '<font color="red">'.$errors['password'].'</font>';?>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <br />
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><label for='password2'>Repeat Password:</label></td>

            <td><input type='password' id='password2' name='password2' />

                <?php echo empty($errors['password2']) ? '' : 
'<font color="red">'.$errors['password2'].'</font>';?>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <br />
            </td>
        </tr>                
        <tr>
            <td><label for='gender'>Gender:</label></td>
            <td><select id='gender' name='gender'>
                    <option value="Male">Male</option>
                    <option value="Female">Female</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <br />
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Start!' /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <br />
            </td>
        </tr>                
    </table>
</form>
<form action="" method='post'>
    <table id="login">
        <?php echo empty($errors['login']) ? '' : '<font color="red">'.$errors['login'].'</font>';?>
        <tr>
            <td><input type='text' name='user' value="<?php echo $username;?>" /></td>
        </tr>


        <tr>
            <td><input type='password' id='password' name='password' /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><button type="submit">Login</button></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

CSS:

```css
#login {
    width: 30%;
    margin-left: 60%;
    font: bold italic 12px/30px Georgia, serif;
    background: rgba(54, 25, 25, .5);
}
table, th, td {
    border-collapse:collapse;
    width:30%;
    margin-left:20%;
    font: bold italic 12px/30px Georgia, serif;
    background: rgba(54, 25, 25, .5);
}
```

Comment: Here's a fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/2KuZr/

Comment: In regards to Stackoverflow syntax; you don't need the ticks (\`) if you're indenting 4 spaces. the tick (\`) syntax is for putting a piece of code with in a line of normal text. Indenting 4 spaces is for longer code, like you have.

Comment: Why are you using a huge table when you could use a few 'div' tags?

Comment: Thank you all for the quick responses! As you can already see, I'm really new at this - I need this for a project for the course I go to, but I seem to be very lost.<br/> I added a JSFiddle and as far as the tables/divs go - the table is basically the way they've taught us do it =[ <br/> Thanks for the syntax note, @bzupnick!

Comment: It seems to be even overe here: http://jsfiddle.net/CWwvC/2/

Comment: Because you're new, you're forgiven, but don't say "you can see the issue here" as the only description of the problem. Especially if it's about aesthetics! What if people think it looks pretty already? So explain what the issue is and how you want it to look.